# Select the sum of the column with the higher value in reach row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table:

```
a   b
-----
1   3
4   3
2   1
```

From where I would like to select the sum of whichever value is higher between a and b.

I've tried with the following query but `SUM()` doesn't recognise the value I want him to sum.

```
SELECT IF(a > b, a, b) AS number, SUM(number) FROM table;
```

Comment: In logical query processing, SELECT happens all together at the same time thats why, it doesn't recognize alias you are specifying in your SELECT. So just use your condition again instead of using alias.

Comment: Thank you, `SELECT SUM(IF(a > b, a, b))`, that is basically a synonymous for the answer, also works perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `case`

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN a > b THEN a ELSE b END)
FROM table
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this IF():

```
SELECT SUM( IF( a > b, a, b ) ) FROM test
```

or case

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN a > b THEN a ELSE b END) FROM test
```

Sql Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/204f7/1